# Lasers path through flames

Tags: visible-light, laser

It was a fine morning and I was cleaning up my room. I found a green laser inside my cupboard. 
I just kindled a spark on my candle and it started to glow.  I took my laser  and pointed on the candle and it didn't allow the  laser to hit the back wall. And I know that it's because the wax is opaque and neither I can see what's behind it on the back wall.

When I pointed the laser on the fire,  I found the green point on the back wall.  It was weird because I cannot see what's behind the fire. It is not transparent.But **How could a laser finds all the way to pass through it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A laser is an coherent electromagnetic wave and it does not interact with light, which is incoherent electromagnetic waves. It displays interference patterns only with [another coherent laser beam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU), when in superposition..

The flame is a mixture of [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) and heated burning( light emitting ) molecules. The part of the laser beam that hits molecules will be deflected but plasma is mostly empty so the light goes through without interference.

Comment: superposition means?

Comment: Superposition means the overlap and sum  of the photon wavefunctions  which make up the laser  beam(s). Because measurements are given by the probability , i.e. the complex conjugate square of the wavefunctions, interference terms appear  , if you watch the video. The beams (photons) are not scattering off each other, in contrast to interactions. photon photon interactions are very improbable at optical  frequencies. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics

Comment: Does that mean that the laser beam that does make it through curve? or does it require intense heat to make light bend?

Comment: @C.Jordan  no. it does not interact or interfere with non coherent beams, curving would mean interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion you made that the flame is not transparent because you can't see behind is wrong. If you cannot see through the flame, it is because the flame's light is too intense.

A flame is a transparent medium for a green laser. 
The laser can be deviated locally because of the gas density in the flame, which induces changes of the refraction index (like a beam devited through a glass).

For some specific wavelengths related to the molecule in the flame, a laser can be absorbed. The study of light emitted by flames is the combustion spectroscopy .

Comment: "it is because the flame's light is too intense" wow.

Comment: For instance if you look at the flame of a lighter, you will see through the flame at the point it is blue. But when the light color changes and become yellow, it become also more intense and you cannot see through it anymore.